# Time to download data

Tags: calculus

*A file of size $100$ mb has to be downloaded. The browser constantly shows a time of $10$ seconds to complete from the time it starts downloading. What time does it take to download **$50$** mb?*
I know that the download speed is **decreasing**. But is it at a constant rate? 
I figured out an answer of **5.6** seconds. Is this correct. If not how to approach the problem?
Thankyou.

Comment: How much of the file has downloaded when the browser shows 10 seconds? It seems to me like that would be important here. Are there any details (such as this) that you might be leaving out?

Comment: Hint: do you have a formula for half-life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S(t)$ be the amount, in mb, that has been downloaded after a time $t$. Now, lets think about the rate of change of $S$.

At time $t=0$ none of the file has been downloaded. We still have $100$mb to download, and according to the browser, we are downloading at a rate of $100$mb per $10s$. More concisely, this means the following:

$$S(0) = 0$$
$$\frac{dS}{dt} = 10$$

Now consider some later time, call it $t_{10}$, at which $10$mb have been downloaded. Now, there are $90$mb remaining, so the download rate is $90$mb per $10s$ according to the browser. Here, we have:

$$S(t_{10}) = 10$$
$$\frac{dS}{dt} = \frac{100 - 10}{10}=\frac{90}{10}$$

One can conjure more examples. But, it is straightforward to note that, in general, we have:

$$\frac{dS}{dt} = \frac{100-S}{10}$$

This is a separable differential equation, which can be solved via [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) to obtain:

$$S(t) = 100 - Ae^{-t/10}$$

where $A$ is some constant. We know that $S(0) = 0$. Applying this to the above expression you find that $A=100$, so:

$$S(t)=100(1-e^{-t/10})$$

With this expression you can solve your problem. You want to know the time $t$ that it takes for $S$ to reach $50$mb.